# Scala : modify values in a TreeMap

Tags: scala, scala-collections

This is a Scala newbie question.

I'm storing some data in a `TreeMap`, where the values keep on modifying. For example, in the below class there is a map which contains orders being sent to the market and I want to keep track of the quantity of orders and each price. This map will change at each order which goes to the market.

```
class MyData {
    // Price -> Quantity map
    var orders: TreeMap[Int, Int] = TreeMap.empty
}
```

Now, when a new order comes at a price of 100, I can add it to the map.

```
var a = new MyData;
// new order at price 5 with qty 200
a.orders += (5 -> 200)
```

Now, the order at price 5 has been modified to 100. How to do that here with `TreeMap`?

```
a.orders ???
```

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap@updated[B1>:B](key:A,value:B1):scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap[A,B1] ?

Comment: One way is to insert it again: a.orders += (5 -> 100). Is this the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... `TreeMap` is found in `scala.collection.immutable` package.

Notice that `immutable` thing. So `TreeMap` are immutable data-structures which means... you can not modify it in-place. No insertions, no updates, no changes at all. But you can get another copy of it with those modifications applied.

So... to modify, you will have to reassign your `a.orders` to the modified copy.

```
a.orders = a.orders + ( 5, 100 )
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a mutable structure you could use `scala.collection.mutable.Map` in place of your `TreeMap`.